# How to stop r and read input from console?

Tags: r

I'm writing a scraping project to extract information (profile) from a job website. I want the user to send number of profiles & position of profiles from console & this 2 values at the start of my program. I have done the scraping part correctly , i will run the entire program .I just want to know how do i take the input while making R wait for sometime?

I have already most of stackoverflow solution like using readLines or scan.

```
library("dplyr")#pipe operator
library("purrr")#compact
library("rvest")#static webscraping
library("RSelenium")#dynamic webscraping
library("stringr")#str_trim
library("zeallot")#multiple assignment of variables %<-%


##val must contain number of profiles & position of profiles send through ##console , how do i make R wait so that user can send input.
val = 0
FUN3 <- function(n=2) {

  val <<- readline(prompt ="YESS")

  }
FUN3()


#global default settings
##every data frame you create after executing that line will not auto-convert to factors unless explicitly told to do so
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
##Setting the default encoding of string(character) to UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters
options(encoding="utf-8")

#variables defined global for storing values
vector <-  c("name","ind","post","locate","currently_With","role_Hiring")

#assign empty list to each variable
c(name,ind,position,locate,currently_With,role_Hiring) %<-% 
  lapply(vector,function(x) assign(x,list()))

#start selenium server
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4547L,browser="firefox")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mention, `readline()` is a good way to go. It is easier than what you have tried: just add

```
val = readline("Input number of profiles and position: ")
```

This will return the value as a character. If you want two numeric values, use

```
val = as.numeric(strsplit(readline("Input number of profiles and position: ")," ")[[1]])
```

So the user can input the two values separated by a space.
If you want `R` to wait after you input the value, use `Sys.sleep(5)` (this will make `R` wait for 5 seconds)

**edit**

Wrapping it around a function will make the code stop until the user has input the values for `val`.

```
library("dplyr")#pipe operator
library("purrr")#compact
library("rvest")#static webscraping
library("RSelenium")#dynamic webscraping
library("stringr")#str_trim
library("zeallot")#multiple assignment of variables %<-%

function1 = function(){
 val = as.numeric(strsplit(readline("Input number of profiles and position: ")," ")[[1]])

 #global default settings
 ##every data frame you create after executing that line will not auto-convert to factors unless explicitly told to do so
 options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 ##Setting the default encoding of string(character) to UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters
 options(encoding="utf-8")

 #variables defined global for storing values
 vector <-  c("name","ind","post","locate","currently_With","role_Hiring")

 #assign empty list to each variable
 c(name,ind,position,locate,currently_With,role_Hiring) %<-% 
  lapply(vector,function(x) assign(x,list()))

 #start selenium server
 rD <- rsDriver(port = 4547L,browser="firefox")
 remDr <- rD[["client"]]
}
```

Then just have the user call `function1()`

Comment: Ty sir for replying. But can u plzz tell where to add Sys.sleep in my code.

Comment: Sir i have tried Sys.sleep() , but still the R wont stop to get the input from console & val will be still 0. While Running entire program R should wait except input from console & then move forward & Sys.sleep wont help it.

Comment: I don't know if I get what you want to do... Assuming you are developing this code for other people to use, I would recommend wrapping it in a function. I will update my answer.

Comment: well if you dont put it in a function and run everything, it will keep on running over the `readline()` and just read the next line of code, which messes up everything else.